# REST convention for DELETE and UNDELETE

Tags: rest, uri, naming-conventions

wondering how can I use a single endpoint for these operations. It's not actually a delete but setting the flag deleted = 0 or 1 so I'm thinking about `put`, if it's an actual deletion, I'd use DELETE (please confirm this point as well)

but How do I differentiate between these two calls on the server side.

```
PUT /product/:id   (to delete)
PUT /product/:id   (to undelete)
```

OR

```
DELETE /product/:id (to delete)
DELETE /product/:id (to undelete)
```

**Edit**
I've PUT already in place for regular update of the product, let's say it's name, quantity etc. so it's kinda in conflict with regular update vs. undelete. Please advise for this as well

Comment: @LutzHorn comment please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Since you can't use PUT) I would recommend:

```
DELETE /product/:id   (to delete)
PATCH /product/:id  (to update/undelete)
// and just send a simple payload/query parameter specifying the `IsActive` bit.)
```

And for the PATCH I would have a bit to undelete it, so its and update of a subset of fields.  On the server you would have one controller and take a look at the http method (`PATCH`| `DELETE`)

Comment: but I've PUT already in place for updating the product details, It's kind conflicting with my existing update operation vs undelete, know what I mean?

Comment: You could do a `PATCH` and just send the `IsActive` bit

Comment: i like the PATCH, so in reality PATCH is used for marking as deletion or isActive bit, the actual deletion (removing row) will happen with DELETE

Comment: something related to this, I've two pages, one to display active products `/GET products` and the other to display trashed (or inactive products) (same endpoint) `/GET products`. Can you please add to the answer on how do I differentiate between displaying the two kinds